# JMeter doesn't save parameter for Java Request

Tags: java, parameters, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to add to existed Java request new parameter. 
I could add it.However, after save it disappears.

Here is look when new param is added:

[image]

After pressing save for this test plan:

[image]

I couldn't understand why does this happen.
Version of JMeter - 2.11
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello there this is a JMETER known bug: [Only default parameters of Java Request Samplers are stored](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42867)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [documentation states](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request)

> The Add/Delete buttons don't serve any purpose at present.

In other words: you can only add a new parameter programmatically in the code of your sampler:

```
@Override
public Arguments getDefaultParameters() {
    Arguments params = new Arguments();
    ...
    params.addArgument("SCENARIOS_ID", "...");
    return params;
}
```

Comment: Small question - after updating params at Java's code, how to see results on UI. Do I need to generate `jar` from sources and put under JMeter's lib folder? Also what if I have 5 params added at Java code -> however on UI I see only 2. Could you please clarify it more?

Comment: Yes, you need to build the JAR and put it in lib folder. If you did that and still have 2 parameters, then either the code is not working, or lib has older version of jar with 2 parameters, in which case you never know which one jmeter will load. So make sure you delete an old version from lib. If code is not working, post your code as a question.

Comment: It's worth noting that although you can only add parameters through code, you CAN edit the values in the JMeter GUI. You only set the defaults in the code.